# How to do some of code in CSS3 and JQuery (IE Compatible)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Now, I'm going to the problem - coding in html and css3 decided to create something, that when you hover on the picture, it enlarge, then turn and disappear, and there is some information out there.

Unfortunately, I noticed that Internet Explorer versions 5 to 8 mentioned "css3" of course, refuses to obey. Following a short cut so I decided to use JQuery, specifically with hoverpulse (malsup.com/jquery/hoverpulse/)

In Google Chrome works fine with CSS3, JQuery and Internet Explorer - not (somehow I was surprised too) - I just get a dozen different images on each, but they all grow.

I'm sorry for pastebin, but I can't paste all of code, because it use too many html tags or something other.

Here is ALL the code (HTML) that I make: http://pastebin.com/Tak7YKpY
And CSS3 (pastebin too): http://pastebin.com/3xprvmeY

The question is - how to fix it and make it turn around and disappear, because I see that can have problem with this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the CSS issues try to create additional CSS files in which you should use CSS2.
jQuery should work just fine in ie7, 8 &9

Comment: Okay, I think that this will be good idea. But how to do, when I hover mouse on the picture, it enlarge (this I know), then turn and disappear, and there is some information out there (this I dunno)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the size, I would use jquery to alter the css attributes on hover.

```
$("#img_id_here").mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css('width', '200px');
});
```

If you want to use a completely different image, for responsive or other purposes, I would use pure css.

```
<style type="text/css">
.img:hover /* you should apply img class to your image. */
   {
      /* whatever you want to do  */
   }
</style>
```